# パスを通してもファイルが見つからない

Tags: ruby, windows, sinatra

とあるサイトのAPIを利用して、番組表を作り予約、録音ができるweb-uiを作っています。

sinatraで起動したいのですが、requireの部分でcannot load such fileエラーが出てしまいます。

以下index.cgi側

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

require 'date'
require 'json'
require 'digest/md5'
require 'sqlite3'

BASE_PATH = File.dirname Dir.pwd
LIB_DIR   = "#{BASE_PATH}/lib"
LOG_DIR   = "#{BASE_PATH}/log"
BIN_DIR   = "#{BASE_PATH}/bin"
MEDIA_DIR = "#{BASE_PATH}/media"

$:.unshift LIB_DIR

require 'エラーの出るファイル'
```

Windows PowerShellでコマンド入力しています。ruby本体、sinatraはインストール済みです。
以下コマンド側

```
PS C:\> ruby www/index.cgi
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- エラーの出るファイル (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from www/index.cgi:23:in `<main>'
```

エラーの出るファイル名の前に./を付けカレントディレクトリの指定をしましたが、同様のエラー文が出ました。ファイルはcドライブ直下のtest/lib中に格納されています。

```
c:--Ruby22
   |
   -test--lib--エラーの出るファイル
```

以下動作環境

- Windows 8.1
- Ruby 2.2
- sinatra 1.4.7

ファイルの位置か動作環境が悪いのでしょうか？ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$:`(`$LOAD_PATH`)に`C:/Ruby22/test/lib`を追加すれば良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました。解決しました。